# Installing joblib error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, joblib, python-install

I have been getting this error when I try to install joblib. How do I get around it?

```
joblib/test/data/joblib_0.9.4.dev0_compressed_cache_size_pickle_py35_np19.gz_01.npy.z -> build/lib/joblib/test/data
copying joblib/test/data/joblib_0.9.4.dev0_compressed_cache_size_pickle_py35_np19.gz_02.npy.z -> build/lib/joblib/test/data
copying joblib/test/data/joblib_0.9.4.dev0_compressed_cache_size_pickle_py35_np19.gz_03.npy.z -> build/lib/joblib/test/data
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib': Permission denied
```

Comment: ``Permission denied`` -> do what you want to do with a user who has permission to do it

Comment: perform it with `sudo` if you are using Linux or OSX. In case of windows, run it in elevated command prompt

Comment: if you installed that on Mac/Linux from pip do `sudo pip install joblib`

Answer (score 2):

perform the installation with `sudo` if you are using Linux or OSX. In case of windows, run it in elevated command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Thinking you to be present on a linux platform try `sudo pip install joblib`because the /Library folder needs root permission to be accessed.